# Creating CommandBar VBA Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created a macro that allow me to pop up a new toolbar with buttons inside to do a specific action but while I'm trying to run it another error pops up:

[image]

So I google it and I tried many  solution like 
[File=> Option=... Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/fr-fr/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother/la-macro-est-introuvable-ou-a-%C3%A9t%C3%A9/fa3b7827-ad76-46f2-914e-7dbe4bee82de)

But it keep showing me this error and I can't test my macros in a good way 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Probably your security settings don't allow macros. Are you on a machine you manage yourself or is the machine managed by your organization?

Comment: In machine that I'm managing my self i did every single solution that is shown in Forums but nothing is there  something it should mentioned in Code to modify this message ?

Comment: refer to this and answer there  please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286742/macro-is-disabled-by-word-confidentiality