# Macro is disabled by word confidentiality

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to create a macro that PopUp a toolBar containing button for a specific action but the code works fine and I tested every single line but when I run it  a message from word PoPUP and prevent me to run this and I donno why 
PS :  I tried every signle solution in Google and forums
and I'm working with Word 2016 and word 2007
this is My code

```
 Sub AddNewMB()
 Dim myCommandBar As CommandBar, myCommandBarCtl As CommandBarControl
 Dim myCommandBarSubCtl As CommandBarControl

 On Error GoTo AddNewMB_Err

 Set myCommandBar = CommandBars.Add(Name:="Airbus", Position:=msoBarTop, 
 menuBar:=True, Temporary:=False)
 myCommandBar.Visible = True
 myCommandBar.Protection = msoBarNoMove

Set myCommandBarCtl = myCommandBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
With myCommandBarCtl
  .BeginGroup = True
  .Caption = "UnGroup Shapes"
  .Style = msoButtonCaption
  .OnAction = "=UnGroupShapes_click()"
 End With

 Set myCommandBarCtl = myCommandBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
 With myCommandBarCtl
  .BeginGroup = True
  .Caption = "Group Shapes"
  .Style = msoButtonCaption
  .OnAction = "=GroupShapes_click()"
 End With

 Set myCommandBarCtl = myCommandBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
 With myCommandBarCtl
  .BeginGroup = True
  .Caption = "&Set Visibility Off"
  .Style = msoButtonCaption
  .OnAction = "=SampleMenuDisable()"
 End With

 Exit Sub

 AddNewMB_Err:
 Debug.Print Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description
 Exit Sub
 End Sub
 Function GroupShapes_click()
 Dim MyMenu As CommandBar
 Dim myCommandBarClickMe As CommandBarControl
 Dim mydocument As Document
 Set mydocument = ActiveDocument
 On Error Resume Next

 ActiveDocument.Unprotect   'enregistré manuellement
 Dim S As Shape, t As Shape

 On Error GoTo GroupShapes_click_Err

 Set MyMenu = CommandBars("Airbus")
 Set myCommandBarClickMe = MyMenu.Controls(2)

 With CommandBars.ActionControl

 End With


 GroupShapes_click_Err:
 Debug.Print Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description

 End Function


  Function SampleMenuDisable()
  Application.CommandBars("Sample Menu Bar").Visible = False
  Application.CommandBars("Menu Bar").Visible = True
  End Function
```

What I want is to prevent this to happen to every code I use and install this toolBar for everyword I use

this is my  error[image: error]

I need some help I'm stuck here 
thank's in advance

Comment: The line ` Set myCommandBar = ...` is missing an underscore at its end. Other than that your code runs on my PC. Funny thing, the commandbar stays hidden somewhere, but that isn't the fault of your code. Perhaps you can tell me why that should be so. The error message seems to point to a problem with your security settings, not with your code.

Comment: I donno why  , security setting like what ??  can you share me some idea how to resolve this ?  I'm really LOST

Comment: Your error message has a Help button. Follow it. Go to File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings, look at 'Macro Settings' but also all the other options in that dialog.

Comment: Yes , I saw that and I followed the instruction  exactly but nothing same as usual  :(

Comment: anyone please? I can't  carry on this  message is keeping prevent me to do anything

Answer (score 0):

1. Separate your macro from the issue that gives you trouble. You haven't established that the code you published is related to the error message you receive. Take a new document and add the following code to it.

   ```
   Private Sub Test()
       MsgBox "This code is running."
   End Sub
   ```

Save the document as macro enabled. Try to run the code. If it runs, close the document, quit Word. Restart Word, load the document, try to run the code again.
If the code runs in one or both of these scenarios the fault must be with the document that contains the code you posted above or with the code itself. Post the result of your above test here and we can look for the error there.

2. Go to File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings.
   Select 'Macro Settings' on the left. You will see a number of radio buttons. Select the one which says "Enable all macros (not recommended; potentially dangerous code can run)". From your description, this is the setting to blame for your problem. If the review of this setting doesn't solve your problem please post a screenshot of this setting dialog box.

Comment: I tested  the first solution and it worked fine so I decided to change the location of my code to another word but it showed the error again  so I think that  there is something preventing adding new Tools or modifying the original action  in word  , So  I went to the second solution to test and I modified all the settings as recommended but  nothing the message keeps showing up  for no reason . I have one solution  but  I don't  know  if this will work , If you can create or modify a macro similar to it  so I can test it to ensure  better locate the problem . My orig code is still up there

Comment: Place apostrophes before all lines of code in all the procedures you suspect. Try to run the code, first just the empty procedure(s), then remove the apostrophe one line at a time while you keep trying to run the code - until you find the one line which is causing the error. As I said earlier, the code ran fine on my PC but failed to create a visible control. The control is created. I can read its properties but I can't see it. I think that is a different error, perhaps positioning or size, but not rejecting your code.